# Выбрать данные по подстрокам mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы (`brands` и `symbols`)  c полями (`brand`,`num` и `symb`,`number` соответственно) (Взял для примера несколько строк, на самом деле их гораздо больше).

[image: brands],   [image: symbols]

Как найти вхождение символов поля `symb` таблицы `symbols` в  поле `brand` таблицы `brands` и обновить поле `num`, чтобы на выходе было так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE `brands` SET `num` = (SELECT `number` FROM `symbols` WHERE `brands`.`brand` RLIKE `symbols`.`symb` LIMIT 1);